# Как проверить интервалы времени запросом к таблице?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет! Имеется такой массив временных интервалов.

```
 array:12 [
  0 => "09:30"
  1 => "10:10"
  2 => "10:50"
  3 => "11:30"
  4 => "12:10"
  5 => "12:50"
  6 => "13:30"
  7 => "14:10"
  8 => "14:50"
  9 => "15:30"
  10 => "16:10"
  11 => "16:50"
]
```

И имеется такой пример записи.

```
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+--------+------------+----------+------------+
| id | service_id | employee_id | id_customer | notes  | start_time | end_time | date       |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+--------+------------+----------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |           1 |           5 | String | 12:00:00   | 12:40:00 | 2020-12-31 |
+----+------------+-------------+-------------+--------+------------+----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

И нужно сделать запрос, который будет проверять все интервалы из массива с записями из таблицы по полям `start_time` и `end_time`. Интервалы, которые в таблицы уже как-бы заняты и нужно вывести лишь те, которые свободны, то есть в данном примере интервал из массива `12:10` будет занят и результатом будут все интервалы, кроме этого интервала. Возможен ли такой запрос?

Или придется сначала вывести все записи из таблицы и сравнивать их с каждым интервалом из массива? То есть этот вариант на уровне php будет, а хотелось бы на уровне mysql. Ведь записей из таблицы может быть много, что очень будет плохо.

Можно ли такой запрос сделать?

То есть нужно как-бы сделать так, чтобы mysql возвращал список свободных интервалом, а так же, чтоб он их проверял с записями из таблицы. Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Если сделать в mysql таблицу, где будут обозначены все "интервалы" в datetime, а не хранить их только в коде php, то это можно сделать и запросом.

Пример запроса не приведу, но такое возможно.

Нужно будет сделать всё то же самое, что делалось бы в коде в плане логики проверки на попадание в интервал.

Comment: @Chippa А если без доп. таблицы?  Возможно?

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать реализацию данного функционала именно на уровне mysql, то без доп. таблицы не обойтись, я думаю, иначе откуда в запросе брать информацию об "интервалах".

Только если в запросе не захардкодить это как-то(выглядит, как костыль), если уж совсем напряжно с создание доп. таблицы.

А какие у вас проблемы с создание таблицы, если не секрет ? 

К БД доступа нет или база уже в продакшене наполнена данными ?

Comment: Эти периоды создаются для сервиса. У сервиса имеется график работы. И в пн он работает по одним периодом, в вт он работает по другим и т.д.. И получается, что таких периодов будет  n*7*(~10), где n это кол-во сервисов, 7 это кол-во дней в недели. И это достаточно много записей будет, что не хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Привет**

Если не хочешь делать проверку диапазонов на стороне `php`, или создавать новую таблицу в БД, то попробуй оформить вложенный запрос, например:

```
select unnest(array[
  '09:30',
  '10:10',
  '10:50',
  '11:30',
  '12:10',
  '12:50',
  '13:30',
  '14:10',
  '14:50',
  '15:30',
  '16:10',
  '16:50'
]) as period
```

Далее сделай `LEFT JOIN` своей таблицы и **развлекайся**.

Comment: Оооо.. кажется то что нужно. Буду пробовать

Comment: Так эта функция unnest для postgres? В mysql нету такой функции и нету типа array